# undefined index in php using post but it can echo the value using request on update.php

Tags: php, mysql

I have these two files and i am updating a table but on the update.php file i get error saying Notice: Undefined index: pname , $pcode...... `$pname = $_POST["pname"];` here i am storing pname value in pname variable.but it shows error

```
                        <address>

                           <div class="control-group">



                                    <label class="control-label">Product Name:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input id="pname" name="pname" type="text" value="<?php echo $PName; ?>"
                                        class="input-xlarge">
                                        <p class="help-block"></p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Code:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input id="code" name="pcode" type="text"  value="<?php echo $PCode; ?>"
                                        class="input-xlarge">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Price:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <input id="price" name="pprice" type="text" value="<?php echo $PPrice; ?>"
                                        class="input-xlarge">

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                            <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Availability:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <select id="stock" name="stock" class="input-xlarge">

                                            <option value="1" selected="selected">Available</option>
                                            <option value="0">Not Available</option>

                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                          </div>

                              <div class="control-group">
                                    <label class="control-label">Product Description:</label>
                                    <div class="controls">
                                        <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="description" > <?php echo $PDescription; ?> </textarea>
                                    </div>
                          </div>


                               <div class="control-group">
                                    Picture 1 :
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
                                    <input  type="file" name="pic1"
                                        class="input-xlarge">

                                    </div>
                          </div>

                           <div class="control-group">
                                    Picture 2 :
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
                                    <input  type="file" name="pic2"
                                        class="input-xlarge">

                                    </div>
                          </div>


                             <div class="control-group">
                                    Picture 3 :
                                    <div class="controls">
                                     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="3000000" />
                                    <input  type="file" name="pic3"
                                        class="input-xlarge">

                                    </div>
                          </div>


                              <div class="control-group">

                                    <div class="controls">
                                    <input type='hidden' name='id' value="<?php echo $ID; ?>"><br/>
                                        <input type="submit" value="UPDATE" class="btn-large" />

                                    </div>
                                </div>


                              </form>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: The error is not in the code you posted but in your PHP handler. We need to see what's in there also.

Comment: I guess you only get this notice the first time you visit the page? (Meaning: didn't submit the form.) After a form submit, it shouldn't display that notice. - If it's still displaying after that, we'd need to see more code. Otherwhise, use one of the suggestions displayed below.

Answer (score 0):

Do you check for form submit?

```
if (isset($_POST["pname"])) {
    // do all your form processing here.
}
```

Comment: [Same comment goes for you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18836352/undefined-index-in-php-using-post-but-it-can-echo-the-value-using-request-on-upd#comment27788596_18836392)

Answer (score 0):

```
$pname= (isset($_POST["pname"]) ? $_POST["pname"] : "");
```

this will check if pname exists in $_POST and then sets it.

you receive that error because you dont have set $_POST["pname"]

Comment: this worked for me $pname = empty($_POST['pname']) ? '' : $_POST['pname'];